# My Goal is to take Image from user and resize it and then upload it to azure mobile app easy tables but I am geting exception

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I am working on visual stdio xamarin.android My requirement is to take image from gallery and show in image view and then uploading it on azure mobile easy table my code is below please help where is my mistake

My Client Data class is :

```
class ClientData
  {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "UserName")]
    public string userName { set; get; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Passward")]
    public string passward { set; get; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Phone")]
    public string phone { set; get; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "City")]
    public string city { set; get; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Work")]
    public string work { set; get; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProfilePic")]
    public string profile { set; get; }
   }
```

And my Activity code is:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using Android.Graphics;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Sync;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.SQLiteStore;
using Android.Util;

namespace CarryARideAnyWere
 {
    [Activity(Label = "SignUpActivity", Theme = "@style/MyAppTheme")]
public class SignUpActivity : Activity
{
    AutoCompleteTextView Cities;
    EditText userName;
    EditText passward;
    EditText retypePassward;
    EditText phone;
    EditText work;
    Button register;
    ImageView profilePic;
    Bitmap bit;
    byte[] b;
    private MobileServiceClient client;
    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<ClientData> clientData;
    const string LocalDBFileName = "ClientDataFile";
    const string ApplicationURL =        "http://carryarideanywhere.azurewebsites.net/";
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SignUp);
        //perform plateform related initialization
        CurrentPlatform.Init();
        //to get City of user
        Cities = FindViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(Resource.Id.City);
        //geting Layout widgets
        userName = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.userName);
        passward = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.passward);
        retypePassward = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.reenterpass);
        phone = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.PhoneNumber);
        work = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.work);
        profilePic = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.profilepic);
        register = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Register);
        //Geting Array of Cities
        String[] citiesofPak =     Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.cities);
        Cities.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,         Resource.Layout.CitiesView, citiesofPak);

        //Creating client object 
        client = new MobileServiceClient(ApplicationURL);
        //Initializing LocalStore 
        await InitLocalStoreAsync();
        clientData = client.GetSyncTable<ClientData>();
        //Defining Click Event of Register button

        register.Click += OnRegisterClick;
        //registering click event of image view
        profilePic.Click -= OnProfilePicClick;
        profilePic.Click += OnProfilePicClick;
       b = new byte[] { 12, 12, 12, 12 };



    }
    private void OnRegisterClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (userName.Text == string.Empty | passward.Text == string.Empty |          retypePassward.Text == string.Empty | phone.Text == string.Empty |     Cities.Text == string.Empty | work.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            CreateDialog.CreateAndShowDialog("Please fill all the Boxes",   "Error", this);
            return;
        }
        if (passward.Text != retypePassward.Text)
        {
            CreateDialog.CreateAndShowDialog("passward Does not match", "Error", this);
            return;
        }
        AddData();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(LogInActivity));
        intent.PutExtra(Constants.Start, true);
      //  StartActivity(intent);
     //   this.Finish();


    }
    private async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
    {
        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(LocalDBFileName);
        store.DefineTable<ClientData>();
        await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
    }
    private async Task PushData()
    {
        try
        {


            await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
            IMobileServiceTableQuery<ClientData> query = clientData
                                                     .Where(u => u.phone == phone.Text);
            await clientData.PullAsync(null, query);
        }
        catch (Java.Net.MalformedURLException)
        {
            CreateDialog.CreateAndShowDialog(new Exception("There was error creating MobileService verify URL"), "Error", this);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            CreateDialog.CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error", this);
        }
    }
    public async void AddData()
    {
        if (client == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var Data = new ClientData { userName = userName.Text, passward =     passward.Text, phone = phone.Text, city = Cities.Text, work =     work.Text,profile=convert(bit)};
        try
        {
            CreateDialog.CreateAndShowDialog(convert(bit).Length.ToString(), "bytearrylength", this);

            await clientData.InsertAsync(Data);
            await PushData();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            CreateDialog.CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error in datauploading", this);
        }

    }
    private void OnProfilePicClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetType("image/*");
        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
       StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select a pic"), 0);
    }
    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
        {
               bit = calculateRequiredimentions(data.Data, 150, 150);
            Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data.Data);
            bit = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
            profilePic.SetImageBitmap(bit);

        }
    }
    private string convert(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        byte[] bitmapData;
        string ImageEncoding;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);



            bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
            ImageEncoding=Base64.EncodeToString(bitmapData,Base64Flags.Default);
            CreateDialog.CreateAndShowDialog(bitmapData.Length.ToString(), "bytearrylength", this);
        }
        return ImageEncoding;
    }
    private Bitmap calculateRequiredimentions(Android.Net.Uri data,int requestedHeight,int requestedWidth)
    {
        Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.InJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream);
        options.InSampleSize = calcualteintvalue(options, requestedHeight, requestedWidth);
        stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(data);
        options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap map = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(stream,null,options);
        return map;
    }
    private int calcualteintvalue(BitmapFactory.Options options,int requestedHeight,int requestedWidth)
    {
        int height = options.OutHeight;
        int width = options.OutWidth;
        int returendValue = 1;
        if (height > requestedHeight || width > requestedWidth)
        {
            int halfheight = height / 2;
            int halfwidth = width / 2;


            while ((halfheight / returendValue) > requestedHeight && (halfwidth / returendValue) > requestedWidth)
            {
                returendValue *= 2;
            }
        }
        return returendValue;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: my Client Data class is ;

Comment: Did you get any error message ?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to add the exception text, including any inner exceptions

Comment: the exception I am getting is: Push operation has failed.See the Push Result for Details;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some obvious problems:

1. Your connection is http - it needs to be https.
2. You have a query specified in your PullAsync() but no query name, so there is no incremental sync
3. You haven't included updatedAt, createdAt and version for incremental sync and conflict resolution
4. You are storing binary data in a string - you can't do that
5. You are assuming your data is less than 255 bytes (the maximum size of a string in easy tables)

There are probably other things as well, but you have not posted any exception data or looked at backend logs, so there is no way of knowing.

Take a look at the book at http://aka.ms/zumobook, particularly chapter 3 and 4.  Chapter 3 covers table data sync and chapter 4 covers custom APIs and file manipulation.